# Create a Data Modal Class from JSON Response in Swift 3.0?

Tags: swift3, modalviewcontroller

I am a beginner and want to learn how to create `Data Modal Class` from JSON reponse in `Swift 3.0`.Could someone help to work with this with explanation and what are advantages of it with example.Thanks in advance

Comment: This is not how SO works. There are plenty of information available about parsing a JSON response in Swift just here on SO. Do some research and when you get stuck and have a specific question, ask that here. SO is not a free coding website. Without showing some effort, you most probably won't receive an answer.

Comment: @DávidPásztor if a new beginner doesn't know then how will he do ? U voted me down als

Comment: i know how to parse JSON but did not know about this @DávidPásztor that's why i asked

Comment: Assuming you mean `Data Model Class` [here are some related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+json+model)

Comment: @vadian can u explain by example

Comment: Did you click on the link in my comment at read the examples?